# How to Find Words Not Containing Specific Letters?

Tags: python, regex, string

I'm trying to write a code using **regex** and my text file. My file contains these words line by line:

```
nana
abab
nanac
eded
```

My purpose is: displaying the words which does not contain the letters which are given as substring's letters.

For example, if my substring is `"bn"`, my output should be only `eded`. Because `nana` and `nanac` contains "n" and `abab` contains "b".

I have written a code but it only checks first letter of my substring:

```
import re

substring = "bn"
def xstring():
    with open("deneme.txt") as f:
        for line in f:
            for word in re.findall(r'\w+', line):
                for letter in substring:
                    if len(re.findall(letter, word)) == 0:
                        print(word)
                        #yield word
xstring()
```

How do I solve this problem?

Comment: Why regex? There are easier ways to check if two strings share any common letters.

Comment: I'm working on regex to understand it, so I have to

Comment: Why this line? its kind of hard to tell what its doing `for word in re.findall(r'\w+', line):`. Also, ````                for letter in substring:
                    if len(re.findall(letter, word)) == 0:
                        print(word)```

will print any word not containing _either_ of the letters in your substring, not _all_ of them.

Comment: more broadly, heres a great regex resource you should run your expressions through https://regexr.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Xosrov has the right approach, with a few minor issues and typos.  The below version of the same logic works

```
import re

def xstring(substring, words):
    regex = re.compile('[%s]' % ''.join(sorted(set(substring))))
    # Excluding words matching regex.pattern
    for word in words:
        if not re.search(regex, word):
            print(word)

words = [
    'nana',
    'abab',
    'nanac',
    'eded',
]

xstring("bn", words)
```

Answer (score 4):

Here, we would just want to have a simple expression such as:

```
^[^bn]+$
```

We are adding `b` and `n` in a not-char class `[^bn]` and collecting all other chars, then by adding `^` and `$` anchors we will be failing all strings that might have `b` and `n`.

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/ioP2po/1/)

#### Test

```
# coding=utf8
# the above tag defines encoding for this document and is for Python 2.x compatibility

import re

regex = r"^[^bn]+$"

test_str = ("nana\n"
    "abab\n"
    "nanac\n"
    "eded")

matches = re.finditer(regex, test_str, re.MULTILINE)

for matchNum, match in enumerate(matches, start=1):
    
    print ("Match {matchNum} was found at {start}-{end}: {match}".format(matchNum = matchNum, start = match.start(), end = match.end(), match = match.group()))
    
    for groupNum in range(0, len(match.groups())):
        groupNum = groupNum + 1
        
        print ("Group {groupNum} found at {start}-{end}: {group}".format(groupNum = groupNum, start = match.start(groupNum), end = match.end(groupNum), group = match.group(groupNum)))

# Note: for Python 2.7 compatibility, use ur"" to prefix the regex and u"" to prefix the test string and substitution.
```

#### RegEx

If this expression wasn't desired, it can be modified/changed in [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/oqUSdc/1/).

#### RegEx Circuit

[jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24) visualizes regular expressions:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check if a string has a set of letters, use brackets.
For example using `[bn]` will match words that contain one of those letters.

```py
import re
substring = "bn"
regex = re.compile('[' + substring + ']')
def xstring():
    with open("dename.txt") as f:
        for line in f:
            if(re.search(regex, line) is None):
                print(line)
xstring()
```

Comment: @Wicaledon my bad, remove the *

Comment: Be careful using a made up example word like `1-zone` You might expect `abab` but `1-z` is a character range.

Comment: thanks for the answer, it works perfectly. But I have a question. Is there any way to write `if ...` without `if(re.search(regex, line) is None):` ?

Answer (score 0):

It might not be the most efficient but you could try doing something with set intersections the following code segment will print the the value in the string word only if it does not contain any of the letters 'b' or 'n'

```
if (not any(set(word) & set('bn'))):
        print(word)
```